# Creating NewTask in a For Loop using Omnithread Library

Tags: multithreading, delphi, otl

am writing a program that detects USB Insertion and saves the Inserted Drive(s) to a StringList.
Now I want to create a NewTask or Background Worker for each Content of the StringList, start them immediately and wait till all task finishes using OmniThread Library.

Here is my Code Snippet

```
uses

  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Winapi.ShellApi, OtlCommon,
  OtlCollections,
  OtlParallel, Vcl.Dialogs;

procedure TUSB.WMDeviceChange(var Msg: TMessage);
var
  lpdbhHeader: PDevBroadcastHeader;
  ResStringList, TempSenderList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;

begin
  lpdbhHeader := PDevBroadcastHeader(Msg.LParam);
  ResStringList := TStringList.Create;
  TempSenderList := TStringList.Create;
  ResStringList.Clear;
  TempSenderList.Clear;

  try
    case Msg.WParam of
      DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        begin
          if (lpdbhHeader^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME) then
          begin

            Sleep(2000);
            // Procedure to get connected USB Devices and save to a StringList

            (GetDrive(PDevBroadcastVolume(Msg.LParam), ResStringList));

            for i := 0 to ResStringList.Count - 1 do
            begin
              { How do I create a NewTask or
                Background Worker for each content in ResStringList
                to execute WalkDirectory and Parallel.ForEach(0, TempSenderList.Count - 1)
                in the NewTask? }

              // Procedure to Recurse content of the USB Drive and Save to TempSenderList

              WalkDirectory(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ResStringList.Strings
                [i]), TempSenderList);

              Parallel.ForEach(0, TempSenderList.Count - 1).Execute(
                procedure(const value: Integer)
                begin

                  // DoSomeThing(TempSenderList[value]);

                end);

              ShowMessage(TempSenderList.Text);

            end;

          end;
        end;
      DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE:
        begin
          if (lpdbhHeader^.dbch_devicetype = DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME) then
          begin
            // ShowMessage('Removed');
          end;

        end;
    end;
  finally
    ResStringList.Free;
    TempSenderList.Free;
  end;

end;
```

Using Delphi XE7 and OmniThread Library v3.04.

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: @gabr did u saw http://pages.videotron.com/aminer/rwlock.html ?
the developer says his (achieved) goal was to outperform TOmniMREW, so if it is true perhaps you can use it to enhance yours